# How to check given domain name http or https in java?

Tags: java, android, validation, url

**My problem**

In my android application I get url input from user, like "www.google.com".

I want to find out for the given url whether to use `http` or `https`.

**What I have tried**

after referring to some Stack Overflow questions I tried with **getScheme()**

```
try {
    String url_name="www.google.com";
    URI MyUri = new URI(url_name);
    String http_or_https="";
    http_or_https=MyUri.getScheme();
    url_name=http_or_https+"://"+urlname;
    Log.d("URLNAME",url_name);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But my above code throws an exception.

**My question**

**Is above approach getScheme() correct or not?**

If above approach is incorrect, how to find url http or https?

Comment: basically i think you should assume it as http and not https since for using https you may need certitifcates for that server to trust incase u r fetching from data from that url

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If neither http or https is explicitly specified than there is nothing for you to find out. An url does have an inherent preference for either one of them. They just specify two different ways to request days from the url.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Because I load all data`s when user login.If I give two requests it takes more time.

Comment: @ranjith how is the choice of http or https relevant for that? If you want to use the url specified by the user then use the url exactly as entered. Otherwise if you want to encrypt the communication than you always need to use https. Your question does not make sense at all.

Comment: @ranjith: What library are you using to retrieve content from the URL? Have you tried checking the documentation for it, or just passing the URL without a scheme (e.g., "//google.com"), to see if it supports automatically figuring this out for you? As others have noted, you can't figure this out solely from the user input; you'd need to actually communicate with the serve.

Comment: @zjs I am using HttpPost..It need url with scheme..

Comment: "how to find url http or https?" -- that is not a URL. It is a domain name. A domain name does not have a scheme.

Comment: Check for port 443 for that server which is used for SSL if not then use http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A domain name is a domain name, it has nothing to do with protocol. The domain is the WHERE, the protocol is the HOW.

The domain is the location you want to go, the protocol is how do you go there, by bus, by plane, by train or by boat. It makes no sense to ask 'I want to go to the store, how do I ask the store if I should go by train or by car?'

The reason this works in browsers is that the browser usually tries to connect using both http and https if no protocol is supplied.

If you know the URL, do this:

```
    public void decideProtocol(URL url) throws IOException {
            if ("https".equals(url.getProtocol())) { 
                // It is https
            } else if ("http".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
                // It is http
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks...clear explanation about domain vs protocol..I understand my question was no sense..

Answer (score 4):

You can check, the given url is http or https by using [URLUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html).

[URLUtil.isHttpUrl(String url);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isHttpUrl(java.lang.String))  returns True if the url is an http.

[URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(String url);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isHttpsUrl(java.lang.String))  returns True if the url is an https.

Comment: Any non-android lib alternative? Guava, Apache commons..?

Comment: This is an Android lib

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Apache [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html#UrlValidator-long-).

You can specify the allowed url schema and in your case the code look something like this:

```
String[] schema = {"https"};
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);

if (urlValidator.isValid("http://foo.bar.com/")) {
   System.out.println("url is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("url is invalid");
}

if (urlValidator.isValid("https://foo.bar.com/")) {
   System.out.println("url is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("url is invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A hierarchical URI is subject to further parsing according to the syntax
[scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]

so your url_name lack of scheme. 
if url_name is "https://www.google.com", so the scheme is https.

refer： http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Comment: Thanks for info..I understand my approach is incorrect.. then How can I found scheme with user input "www.google.com"

Comment: absolutely，there are lots of official URI schemes, so we cannot get scheme only from the input. Such as, (http:// + my.file) is vaild, (https:// + my.file) is vaild and (ed2k:// + my.file) is also vaild.  refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: so I can`t get scheme from input. this is your answer?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** get it from just URL. It doesn't make sense. Some websites can work with both **http** & **https**. It depends upon website itself whether they use SSL certificate or not.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, if a user didn't dare to provide full url including protocol type. The app might use kind of trial and error approach, try to establish connection using the list of available protocols. (http, https). The successful hit might be considered as a default. Again, all this about usability,this method is better than just annoying an inattentive user with ugly error message.

Comment: thanks for answer..I already use your suggestion(establish connection using the list of available protocols).It takes more code.. But I want to reduce the code..If any other possible to get protocol?

Answer (score 0):

ranjith- I will store some sort of mapping between URI (main domain) and preferred protcol within application..can have pre-defined mappings based on what you know and then let that mapping grow as more Uris added..