# How to add a protocol to a URL if it does not exist? (in an Android app)

Tags: android

I am working on an app that gets a URL link from the user via edit text widget. How can I check if a given URL has a protocol? And if it doesn't, how can I add the correct protocol for the specific URL?

For example if the user entered: `google.com`
how can I make it become: `https://google.com`

The main problem is knowing the correct URL protocol for a given address (is it `http/https/ftp`? and so on).

Comment: Just compare the your output string with `.contains()` property.

Comment: Check out : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check given domain name http or https in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597682/how-to-check-given-domain-name-http-or-https-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.startsWith() to check if the url String starts with http:// or not

```
public String valid_url(final String url)
    {
        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
            {
               return "http://" + url;
            }
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: `||` in your if condition is wrong. because when the url string looks something like `https://stackoverflow.com` and you pass it on this function the result would be:
`http://https://stackoverflow.com`. replacing `||` with `&&` would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

first check if url has protocol using .contains() method
and get protocol using .indexof() and .substring() method

```
string url = editText.getText().toString();
string protocol;

if(url.contains("://")){
    //url has a protocol
    int index = url.indexof("://");
    //get protocol 
    protocol = url.substring(0,index-1);


}else{
    //url does not have a protocal
    // add your protocol to begining of the url
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use android web kit URLUTIL class
package android.webkit;

```
URLUtil.guessUrl("your web address/String")
```

**example scenarios:**
[www.testurl.com](http://www.testurl.com)
testurl.com
testurl

**result:**
http://www.testurl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the your output string with `.contains()` property

```
 String value = editText.getText().toString();

 if(!value.contains("https://")) {
    // add https:// to ur string 
 }else {
     // No need to add 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
if(!url.startsWith("www.")&& !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
    url = "www."+url;
 }

if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
    url = "http://"+url;
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

As already adviced use the URL class of the SDK.

Here an example:

```
var urlWithScheme = new URL("https://www.google.com");
var urlWithoutScheme = new URL("www.google.com");

if (urlWithScheme.getProtocol() != null && urlWithScheme.getProtocol().length() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Given URL includes scheme: " + urlWithScheme.getProtocol());
}

if (urlWithoutScheme.getProtocol() != null && urlWithoutScheme.getProtocol().length() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Given URL includes scheme: " + urlWithoutScheme.getProtocol());
} else {
    System.out.println("Url has no Protocol and you can't guess it by the domain name, because under this name all possible services can exist!");
}
```

If the given URL has not protocoll you can't guess it. Because under a domain name there can exist any protocol specific service in parrallel.

I would narrow it down to only support http and https. For this you could write a test like connect to https url, if success use it, because https is prefered. If you get redirect or not connection try http ;)