# How to Open an Url (through intent) Taking input from user(www.xyz.com) and adding http/https efficiently?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app that takes the input url from user (www.xyz.com) and then I am writing this code to hit the link in the browser

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(Url));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I saw that the `http/https` are not added automatically then I added it myself by doing `Uri.parse("http://"+"Url)`. but is there any way to do this task automatically? Can anyone suggest a better solution for it because when I hit the links in my solution I am not sure the link I am hitting is https or http.

Comment: 'Uri.parse()' will only convert the given String to uri. It doesn't know what type of uri/uri is it (http or https). So yes, you have to add it yourself

Comment: check out this link hope this helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597682/how-to-check-given-domain-name-http-or-https-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.parse()` will only convert the given String to uri. It doesn't know what type of url/uri is it (http or https). So yes, you have to add it yourself

Although you can set a static text in your `EditText` so that when user enters the text/url, the `http` or `https`is static and cannot be edited.

```
editText.setText("http://");
Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can check first if the url that user enter starts with http/https or not, if yes, you can ignore, and if no, you can add "http://" by the code

```
String textFromUser = editText.getText().toString();
textFromUser = textFromUser.startsWith("http://") || textFromUser.startsWith("https://") ? textFromUser : "http://" + textFromUser;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(textFromUser));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```